# Log4j2: не пишет логи в файл

Tags: java, log4j2

Я подключил Log4j2

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
```

и прописал следующие настройки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%clr{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}{faint} %clr{%5p} %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n%xwEx"/>
            <!-- Крутое, но бесцветное логирование-->
<!--            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36}.%M():%L - %msg%n}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}"/>-->
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="File" fileName="C:/Users/Mi/output.log" filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.logging.log4j.filelogger" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

В консоль всё отлично пишется, но в файл, почему-то, нет. Я ожидал, что логи будут писаться в файл по адресу `C:/Users/Mi/output.log`, файл автоматически создаётся, он открыт приложением (его нельзя удалить), но логи туда не пишутся. Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Как мне кажется нет доступа к файлу.

Comment: Приложение создало файл, открыло его на запись, но не имеет доступа? Маловероятно.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что было достаточно включить аппендеры в один логер:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="ErrorFile" level="error"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="WarnFile" level="warn"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```